# How can one create a batch file to silent unistall a not MSI string

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installer

Can someone please help on how to create a batch file that can silent unistall the below string without user interaction.

"C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information{4D9CA1B8-5FF5-47A7-8BDF-C37D1F9F55A5}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly -uninst

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck?  What happens when you just put this line into a batch file and run it?

Comment: I tried this: start "" "C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information\{4D9CA1B8-5FF5-47A7-8BDF-C37D1F9F55A5}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly -uninst and it's just bringing up the user interact to unistall, but I need one that will slilently unistall it. thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to silent unistall the mentionned string

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `/removeonly` switch and adding the `/s` switch (for *S*ilent Mode).

More info here: [Setup.exe and Update.exe Command-Line Parameters](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm#wp1021738)

Comment: The user interaction still comes up even when I remove the /removeonly switch and change it with /s